# How to add overlay items in v2 api key maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, google-maps-markers

I am using google map v2 api. I want to show the overlay items when clicking icons in google map. And also if i am tapping that overlay i need to show another view. Is it possible to customize the overlay? If anybody knows kindly share your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: did you read any of the documentation? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: Ya. But i don't have any idea about custom overlay in v2.

Comment: what do you mean a custom overlay? like a different image of a marker?

Comment: When tapping map pin i need to show one image and one text.

Answer (score 1):

You should customize your Info Window, these links can help you:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#info_windows

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter

Answer (score 0):

**overlay** mean put image on map describing what ever you want

this video will describe how to overlay image on map

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vowN3gHAlU

but If you need clear example in android

```
LatLng NEWARK = new LatLng(40.714086, -74.228697);

    GroundOverlayOptions newarkMap = new GroundOverlayOptions()
            .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.newark_nj_1922))
            .position(NEWARK, 8600f, 6500f);
    map.addGroundOverlay(newarkMap);
```

source https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/groundoverlay